# Customize RadGridView to merge Cells in GridView

Tags: wpf, gridview, radgridview

I want to customize RadGridView to merge Cells in GridView, but I have not been found resolved. Can you help me find to resolve that ? Thank you so much!

Comment: What about a more descriptive title? We know that you need help, otherwise you would not ask here ;)

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the current version of RadGridView for Silverlight does not support merging cells. 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/merge-cells.aspx